# How to print my calculations for even and odd integers?

Tags: python

The program instructions follow: Your program should calculate how many values in a list of randomly generated integers are odd and how many are even with the following requirements:

Get the number of values to be generated along with the range of values from the user. After calculating the total number of odd and even values, display the results and allow the user to continue to generate and count new sets of values until they choose to exit.

**Example program run:**

```
Enter number of values needed: 100
Enter high end of value range from 1 to: 50
Odd values: 48.7%
Even values: 51.3%
Do you want to generate a new set of values? (Y/N) Y
Enter number of values needed: 20
Enter high end of value range from 1 to: 100
Odd values: 40.0%
Even values: 60.0%
Do you want to generate a new set of values? (Y/N) N
```

I am able to get it to print the first two prompts, but then it seems that it is infinitely loading.

```
import random
#if play is True when game starts
play = True
while play:
#Prompt user with Enter number of values needed:

    num_values = int(input())
    print("Enter number of values needed:", num_values)
# get user input of how many values to generate for i in range(0, num_values)

    for i in range(0,num_values):
        #Prompt user with Enter high end of value range from 1 to:

        high_end = int(input())
        print("Enter high end of value range from 1 to:", high_end)

        #Get range of values from 1 to user_input list1 = random.randrange(1,user_input)

        list1 = random.randrange(1, high_end)
    def even():
        even_count=0
        if (list1 % 2) == 0:#finds odd numbers
            even_count += 1 #keeps count of even  numbers
        return even_count 

    def odd():
        odd_count=0
        if (list1 % 2) != 0:#finds odd numbers
            odd_count += 1 #keeps count of even  numbers
        return odd_count 
    even_total = even_count / num_values
    odd_total = odd_count / num_values
    print("Odd values:", odd_total)`your text`
    print("Even values:", even_total)



letter = str(input())
print("Do you want to generate a new set of values? (Y/N)", play)
    if letter != 'Y':
        play = False
```

This is my current code, and I am required to have at least two functions. I am unsure as to why my even_values/odd_values are not processing correctly.

Comment: The [tag:pygame]  tag is only intended for questions about [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news),, not questions about writing a game with Python.

Comment: Your functions are not top level... even if they were this code would not run

Answer (score 0):

1. The range consists of two values, it doesn't have to start with 1.
2. The task is to make a list. You create a list1 variable and inside the loop ask for a range for each number
3. You don't call the functions you wrote

   ```
    import random
    play = True
    while play:
        print("Enter number of values needed: ", end = "")
        num_values = int(input())
        print("Enter start of value range from 1 to: ", end = "")
        start = int(input())
        print("Enter end of value range from 1 to: ", end = "")
        end = int(input())
        list1 = []
        for i in range(0,num_values):
            list1.append(random.randint(start, end))
        print(list1)

        def even():
            even_count = 0
            for i in list1:
                if i % 2 == 0:
                   even_count += 1
            return even_count

        def odd():
            odd_count = 0
            for i in list1:
                if i % 2 != 0:
                    odd_count += 1
            return odd_count

        even_total = (even() / num_values) * 100
        odd_total = (odd() / num_values) * 100
        print(f"Odd values:{odd_total}%")
        print(f"Even values:{even_total}%")


        print("Do you want to generate a new set of values? (Y/N)")
        letter = str(input())
        if letter != 'Y':
            play = False
   ```